# Converting Kinect Methods from Beta 2, to Version 1

Tags: c#, kinect

So I have convert the `getDisplayPosition` from the beta version of the Kinect SDK to the full version. Here's what I have right now

#### The Original

```
 private Point getDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    {
        float depthX, depthY;
        nui.SkeletonEngine.SkeletonToDepthImage(joint.Position, out depthX, out depthY);
        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));  //convert to 320, 240 space
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));  //convert to 320, 240 space
        int colorX, colorY;
        ImageViewArea iv = new ImageViewArea();
        // only ImageResolution.Resolution640x480 is supported at this point
        nui.NuiCamera.GetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixel(ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, iv, (int)depthX, (int)depthY, (short)0, out colorX, out colorY);


        // map back to skeleton.Width & skeleton.Height
        return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
    }
```

#### My Version

```
private Point getDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    {
        float depthX, depthY;
        KinectSensor sensor = kinectSensorChooser1.Kinect;
        DepthImageFormat depth = DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30;
        depthX = 320;
        depthY = 240;
        sensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(joint.Position, depth);
        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));
        int colorX, colorY;
        colorX = 320;
        colorY = 240;

        return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
    }
```

Basically I want to know if my version will do the same thing as the original, and if not, how to fix it.

Comment: refer this link it may help you http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-code-migration-from-beta2-to-v1-0-managed/

Comment: I have stumbled aceoss that before in my joirneys, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did and it works for me (this is very similar to yours) - I hope it helps:

#### My Version

```
private Point getDisplayPosition(DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Joint joint)
{ 
    float depthX, depthY;        
    DepthImagePoint depthPoint = kineticSensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(joint.Position, depthImageFormat);

    depthX = depthPoint.X;
    depthY = depthPoint.Y;

    depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
    depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));

    int colorX, colorY;
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = depthFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
    colorX = colorPoint.X;
    colorY = colorPoint.Y;

    return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
}
```

Comment: Sorry cant give bounty via phone:P

Comment: Oh, but wouldn't I also need to have a `DepthImageFrame`? And would that effect anything? Also what is `depthImageFormat` and `sensor`?

Comment: depthImageFormat (DepthImageFormat instance) and Sensor (KineticSensor instance) are a couple variables in my code. I assign these when the window has loaded.

I use depthImageFrame to make use of the built MapToColorImagePoint method.

I used depthImageFormat as my thinking is this is an initialise value on the KineticSensor, so I want to use the same setting in this regard. 

In my code "sensor" is just an instance of KinectSensor instantiated when the window has loaded. Likewise, depthImageFormat is also a variable I assign after starting up the sensor.

Comment: FYI when you said `sensor.ColorStreamFormat`, I found that it is really `sensor.ColorStream.Format`, seeing as '`sensor` has no definition for `ColorStreamFormat`'

Comment: Haha lol no prob good thing I was messig with KinectSensor members that day