# Kinect sdk 1.5 getDisplayPosition method

Tags: wpf, canvas, kinect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Kinect Methods from Beta 2, to Version 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367582/converting-kinect-methods-from-beta-2-to-version-1)

In kinect sdk beta 2, there is a method to get display position of joints. Is there a method at kinect sdk 1.5 which does the same thing or must i write a new method?

```
        private Point getDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    {          

        float depthX, depthY;
        _kinectNui.SkeletonEngine.SkeletonToDepthImage(joint.Position, out depthX, out depthY);
        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));  //convert to 320, 240 space
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));  //convert to 320, 240 space
        int colorX, colorY;
        ImageViewArea iv = new ImageViewArea();
        // only ImageResolution.Resolution640x480 is supported at this point
        _kinectNui.NuiCamera.GetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixel(ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, iv, (int)depthX, (int)depthY, (short)0, out colorX, out colorY);

        // map back to skeleton.Width & skeleton.Height
        return new Point((int)(imageContainer.Width * colorX / 640.0) , (int)(imageContainer.Height * colorY / 480) );
    }
```

this method is taken from Kinect Skeleton.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367582/converting-kinect-methods-from-beta-2-to-version-1, as it is the same question and has an answer.

Comment: I was busy typing an answer to your `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` question and you deleted it .. :) Well, the answer is covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382

Comment: @BalusC Sorry :D I just realize that problem is about ajax and non-ajax buttons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296420/primefaces-fullajaxexceptionhandler-ajax-request

Comment: In your deleted question, you was clearly using `actionListener` instead of `action`. Exceptions which you throw from action listeners do not trigger the error page. Carefully read the link in my previous comment to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

See [Converting Kinect Methods from Beta 2, to Version 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367582/converting-kinect-methods-from-beta-2-to-version-1) for the new, old, and working methods. The working method is:

```
private Point getDisplayPosition(DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Joint joint)
{ 
    float depthX, depthY;        
    DepthImagePoint depthPoint = sensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(joint.Position, depthImageFormat);

    depthX = depthPoint.X;
    depthY = depthPoint.Y;

    depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
    depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));

    int colorX, colorY;
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = depthFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
    colorX = colorPoint.X;
    colorY = colorPoint.Y;

    return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
}
```