# FullAjaxExceptionHandler does not show session expired error page on ajax button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

I have implemented Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler but the problem is It is not working with ajax requests. After session expires when I click to non-ajax button, It works well. It redirects user to custom error page. But if the button uses ajax, It doesn't do anything. Page just stucks.

Edit: I have changed ActionListener to Action and still same.

Edit2: It gives no error. Neither Apache Tomcat output nor Apache Tomcat Log.

[image]

here is my spring security;

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajaxErrorPage" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>        
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
                default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"
                always-use-default-target="true"                                                        
                authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"/>
</http>
```

Comment: What's the contents of the ajax response?

Comment: <p:menuitem value="open a new tab" action="#{myController.openNewTab()}" update=":contentPanel"/> I have a menuitem and when user clicks this menuitem, a tab in tabview will be rendered. By the way everytab includes different pages. Its like Google chrome. User has some bookmarks and if he clicks some bookmark, App will open it's page in a new tab.

Comment: What's the contents of the ajax response? Press F12 in Chrome and check *Network* section to see it.

Comment: @BalusC I added as picture.

Comment: So.. The ajax response is a 302 redirect? Do you have a homegrown login filter which is performing a `response.sendRedirect()` when the user is not logged-in or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sending a synchronous redirect as a response to the ajax request (a HTTP 302 response using e.g. `response.sendRedirect()`). This is not right. The JavaScript ajax engine treats the 302 response as a new destination to re-send the ajax request to. However, that in turn returns a plain vanilla HTML page instead of a XML document with instructions which parts of the page to update. This is confusing and thus the redirected response is altogether ignored. That explains precisely the symptoms you're facing.

The very same problem is also asked and answered in the following closely related questions:

- [FullAjaxExceptionHandler does not redirect to error page after invalidated session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030922/fullajaxexceptionhandler-does-not-redirect-to-error-page-after-invalidated-sessi/)
- [How to move user to timeout page when session expires, if user click on browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766307/how-to-move-user-to-timeout-page-when-session-expires-if-user-click-on-browser/)
- [GET request for redirect initiated by browser but not successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697768/get-request-for-redirect-initiated-by-browser-but-not-successful/)
- [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/jsf-redirect-isnt-working-when-button-submitted/)
- [JSF Filter not redirecting After Initial Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366936/jsf-filter-not-redirecting-after-initial-redirect)

Basically, you need to instruct Spring Security in some way to perform the following conditional check:

```
if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
    // JSF ajax request. Return special XML response which instructs JavaScript that it should in turn perform a redirect.
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    response.getWriter()
        .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
        .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", loginURL);
} else {
    // Normal request. Perform redirect as usual.
    response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
}
```

I'm however no Spring user and I'm not interested to use it, and am therefore not able to give a more detailed answer how to perform this check in Spring Security. I can however tell that Apache Shiro has exactly the same problem which is explained and solved in this blog article: [Make Shiro JSF Ajax Aware](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#MakeShiroJSFAjaxAware).

Comment: What you mean by loginURL? when i set it "/login.xhtml" the application tries to open http://localhost:8080/login.xhtml and gives not found error. When i set "/myApp/login.xhtml" it says "this page has too many redirect" error. Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: It should be `request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml"`. As to the "too many redirects" error, this means that it's redirecting in an infinite loop. Apparently you're also redirecting to login.xhtml when login.xhtml itself is been requested. You should then not redirect to login.xhtml, but continue the request by `chain.doFilter(request, response)`. This answer comes close with what you probably need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14582031/

Comment: problem is when I start the application, request.getRequestURI() comes with "/myApp/" string not with "/myApp/login.xhtml". A little confusing

Comment: It seems that you're just adding a servlet filter instead of reconfiguring Spring Security. You basically need to **change** the Spring Security configuration/logic. This is unfortunately not just a matter of adding a servlet filter. I recommend to re-ask the question in the following context: "How do I change the way how Spring Security redirects the request to the login page? I need to return a XML response to an ajax request instead of a 302 response.".

Comment: I solved the problem but still I don't what is going on behind :D anyway it works now. I changed some lines from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14582031/ ; boolean loginRequest = (request1.getRequestURI().equals(request1.getContextPath() + "/")) || (request1.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL));

Answer (score 1):

In file spring-security (en el archivo de Spring Security)

```
<beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>

<!-- redirection strategy -->
<beans:bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy" class="com.mycompany.JsfRedirectStrategy">
    <beans:property name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/login.xhtml" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionManagementFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    <beans:property name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
</beans:bean>

<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajaxErrorPage" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>        
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
            default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"
            always-use-default-target="true"                                                        
            authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"/>

     <!-- custom filter -->
    <custom-filter ref="sessionManagementFilter"  before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />

</http>
```

The custom redirectStrategy (La estrategia de redirección personalizada)

```
public class JsfRedirectStrategy implements InvalidSessionStrategy
{

    private static final String FACES_REQUEST = "Faces-Request";

    private String invalidSessionUrl;

    public void setInvalidSessionUrl(String invalidSessionUrl) {
        this.invalidSessionUrl = invalidSessionUrl;
    }

    public String getInvalidSessionUrl() {
       return invalidSessionUrl;
    }



    @Override
    public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {



        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        String urlFinal = contextPath+invalidSessionUrl;




        if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader(FACES_REQUEST))) {
            // with ajax
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter()
                .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", urlFinal);
        } else {

            // not ajax
            request.getSession(true);
            response.sendRedirect(urlFinal);

        }

   }
```

work for me.